# Unnecessary object copy - C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

guys, i'm using Standard Template Language and a few months ago I started to read more about it, and implementing some exercises. I have this code here:

```
class Student {
// many attributes and methods here plus:
char* name; // Student name
char* courseName; // Student course name
std::string toString() { return std::string(name); }
}

std::string FindCourseName ( std::list< Student > stu, string name )
{
    for ( std::list< Student >::iterator it = stu.begin();
    it != stu.end();
    it++ )
    {
            if ( (*it).toString() == name )
            {
                return it->courseName;
            }
    }
return "";
}
```

And the exercise asks for:

a)  How many unnecessary object creations/copies are done in the FindCourseName method?
b)  How would you reduce this number of copies?
c)  How would you optimize the code above?

I read this code many times and I can't see any unnecessary object copies, can you guys put a light in my head?hahaha Thanks a lot!

Comment: At a quick glance I see at least 4 (counting the list as one.)

Comment: Hmm, I only see 3.  I also see a few copies that aren't _strictly_ necessary, but I wouldn't remove them.

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually I agree. 3 definitely avoidably ones.

Comment: Several, but the function parameter types are the only changes worth worrying about.  (A tricky note: there are two copies of a lightweight object in the expression `it++`.)

Comment: @aschepler: I sure hope nobody is counting that one, that's so trivial that I doubt anyone would count it.  Homework though...  Maybe a prof might.

Comment: I take back my 3, one of them is a move, not a copy.  Well, only in C++11.  If this is C++03, then that's still a copy.

Comment: Where exactly are the unnecessary copies? I really didn't get the concept.

Comment: Why are you using `char*` instead of `std::string`? Does your class have a copy constructor, a copy assignment operator and a destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the two function parameters capture by value, both `stu` and `name` are *copies* of the things passed in. This is bad.
2. `(*it).toString()` makes a copy of `it->name` as a `string`, but this is debatable, because `string`s are very handy, and hard to screw up, so this sort of thing is common.
3. `it++` returns a copy of what it was before the increment, but most people don't count that because it's so trivially optimized.
4. In C++03, `return std::string(name);` can *sometimes* create an additional temporary string copy of the name.  This is mostly theoretical, so few people count this.
5. Since `FindCourseName` returns a `string`, it makes a copy of the return value as a `string`, but again, this is debatable, because `string`s are good.

Comment: 1. Oh, this is a fact that i didn't remember, in this case it's better pass the parameters by reference, right? I learned this in OO programming in Java, didn't know that the rules were the same for C++. About the other copies, despite being all of them common or theoretical, I think that can count. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, if you want a copy, pass by copy.  If you need to change the original, pass by reference, otherwise pass by const reference.  Keep in mind, when translating Java concepts to C++, all Java variables are C++ _pointers_, and Java passes these pointers by value/copy.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the function the following way according to the request of the assignment provided that the class itself may not be changed and all its data members are private except used in the function class methods

```
std::string FindCourseName ( const std::list< Student > &stu, const string &name )
{
    for ( std::list< Student >::const_iterator it = stu.cbegin(), last = stu.cend();
    it != last;
    ++it )
    {
            if ( (*it).toString() == name )
            {
                return it->courseName;
            }
    }
return "";
}
```

If data member name is public then I would write

```
            if ( (*it).name == name )
            {
                return it->courseName;
            }
```

Though due to optimization and copy/move constructor elision there is no big difference.

Comment: I think you forgot the it++ in the loop.  Should be ++it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Why do you think that the class itself may not be changed?  I didn't get that from the question.

Comment: @Mooing Duck If they are not private then I do not see a sense to define a class and duplicate methods.